# How to get an ?attr/ value programmatically

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm trying to do some custom view styling and I'm having trouble correctly picking up styled attributes from the theme.

For instance, I would like to get the themes EditText's Text Colour.

Looking through the theme stack you can see my theme uses this to style it's EditText's:

```
<style name="Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/editTextBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/editTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
</style>
```

What I'm looking for, is how do I get that ?attr/editTextColor

(Aka, the value assigned by the theme to "android:editTextColor")

Searching through google, I have found enough of this answer:

```
TypedArray a = mView.getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.editTextStyle, new int[] {R.attr.editTextColor});
int color = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
a.recycle();
```

But I'm pretty sure I must be doing this wrong as it always displays as black rather than grey?

Comment: if you want to get color then use `getColor()` method

Comment: also you need `R.attr.textColor`, not `R.attr.editTextColor`

Comment: No, i don't, I want to get the editTextColor. The R.attr.textColor is specific to each component.

Comment: if you say so... then use `Theme#resolveAttribute()` but  what do you need `<item name="android:textColor">` for in such case?

Comment: and if you do some custom view you are normally styling it by using styles, just like `Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText` and not theme's attrs

Comment: I'm using the colour of the EditText to style a custom component in a neighbouring component. I want it to naturally look the same colour as the default editTextColor. Since I'm not changing the colour of my EditText's I don't have a value to reference directly.

Comment: ok so. as i said, if you want to `Retrieve the value of an attribute in the Theme` use `Theme#resolveAttribute()` method

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As commented from @pskink:

```
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.editTextColor, value, true);
    getView().setBackgroundColor(value.data);
```

will pull the attribute from the theme currently assigned to the context.

Thanks @pskink!

Comment: Frist try to respect others answer, you are not paying them, they are helping you.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran first try to respect how this site works. You can assign blame for downvotes but in reality you are just guessing. Just about anyone can downvote a post and you would never know who it was. Anyway, people are free to vote however they choose. Don't get emotional about it

Comment: Muthukrishnan - I downvote answers that detracts value by confusing future viewers while adding no value. It doesn't reflect on what I think of the authors of the answers, I appreciate their attempt and the time it cost them. Downvoting is our way as SO users to curate content - it's function is not to punish users.

Comment: @Graeme, this is to get the attribute value from them, 
is that any way we can set value in attribute programmatically? 
I want to change the color of the theme by changing its attr value. I don't know if I can do that.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this ?

**EDIT :**
This is my short answer if you want a complete answer ask me

Your attrs.xml file :

```
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="yourAttrs">
        <attr name="yourBestColor" format="color"/>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

**EDIT 2 :** Sorry I forgot to show how I'm using my attr value in layout.xml, so :

```
<com.custom.coolEditext
    android:id="@+id/superEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:yourBestColor="@color/any_color"/>
```

and then in your custom Editext :

```
TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.yourAttrs, 0, 0);

try {
    int colorResource = a.getColor(R.styleable.yourAttrs_yourBestColor, /*default color*/ 0);
} finally {
    a.recycle();
}
```

I'm not sure if it is the answer what you want but it can put you on good way

Comment: Thanks MrLeblond. I know how to use and assign styles. I'm hoping to find out how I can find the value assigned to an ?attr/ style variable.

Comment: @etienne Besides the fact that you have no clue who voted on a post, "trying to help" is not the same as providing useful content. People are free to vote however they chose.

Comment: etienne - I did downvote this answer because it doesn't add any value to the subject, in fact it detracts value by confusing future viewers. It doesn't reflect on what I think of MrLeblond and it doesn't mean I don't appreciate his help. Downvoting is our way as SO users to curate content - it's function is not to punish users.

Comment: @Graeme Np. i'm glad you found a solution.